# How to use v4.ViewPager with app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm beginner to android don't know how to use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
with android.app.Fragment and I don't want to use support.v4.app.Fragment
could you suggest me how to work and which library should I use to achieve this funtion

Comment: Better so Search on _Gooogle_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using android.app.Fragment, you need to config you android version minimize from android api 17.

`defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
    }`

And when you using Adapter for viewpager, It should from android.support.v13
Here is example for adapter:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private List<String> dataList;

    public MyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<String> dataList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (dataList != null) {
            return dataList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (dataList != null && dataList.size() > 0 && position < dataList.size()) {
            String str = dataList.get(position);

            return YourFragment.newInstance(str);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And when you create adapter and set for viewpager, it should be getFragmentManager() instead of getSupportedFragmentManager()

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), null);
dvpPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```